# How to resolve "Error in cut.default(x, breaks = breaks, include.lowest = T) : 'x' must be numeric" when using the pheatmap() function in R

Tags: r, pheatmap

sorry for the basic question, but I couldn't find an answer that worked googling elsewhere. I am having trouble running the pheatmap() function in R on a 411 x 341 table with the following format extended to 341 samples and 411 genes:

|  | Sample_1 | Sample_2 | Sample_3 | Sample_4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Gene1 | 1.22 | 3.21 | 4.20 | 1.08 |
| Gene2 | 1.34 | 1.09 | 0.69 | 1.02 |
| Gene2 | 1.34 | 0.80 | 0.81 | 3.51 |
| Gene2 | 1.34 | 2.21 | 0.97 | 1.12 |

When I run the following code:

```
library(readxl)
library(pheatmap)
library(grid)
library(gtable)

setwd("~/Analysis")
Data <- read_excel("mRNA_Expression.xlsx", sheet = "P")

Data <- as.matrix(Data)
Data2 <- Data[,-1]
rownames(Data2) <- Data[,1]

pheatmap(Data2, cluster_rows = T, cluster_cols = F, legend = T)
```

I get the error

```
Error in cut.default(x, breaks = breaks, include.lowest = T) : 
  'x' must be numeric
```

I can't seem to figure out what is causing it. As bet I understand, the cut function is related to clustering, but even if I run the code as simply:

```
pheatmap(Data2, cluster_rows = F, cluster_cols = F, legend = F)
```

I still get the error. Any suggestions on how to fix this issue? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you get if you run `str(Data2)` ?

Comment: > str(Data2)
 chr [1:411, 1:340] "1.22078487" "0.84805630" "0.54354415" "0.71139417" "0.93680497" "0.14129407" "1.01200630" "1.13309505" ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : chr [1:411] "KDM1A" "UPF1" "CREBBP" "KMT2E" ...
  ..$ : chr [1:340] "8_pcw_DFC_NP_13058" "8_pcw_VFC_NP_13058" "8_pcw_MFC_NP_13058" "8_pcw_OFC_NP_13058" ...

Comment: You have `character` data, not `numeric` data.

Comment: It seems clear that `"1.22078487"` is a string, not a number. I suspect that your `as.matrix(Data)` is to blame. Realize that first, while `data.frame` can have different classes for each column, `matrix` cannot, so if _any_ of your columns in `Data` are strings, then `as.matrix(.)` will convert _all_ of them to strings. You likely need to subset your `Data` to be only the number columns. Hastily, try `Data <- as.matrix(Data[,sapply(Data, is.numeric)])`, though that is a hack to fix this current symptom. Know your data (`Data`) better :-)

Comment: Another thought: I'm going to guess that what you _think_ should be row-names is actually a real column. If in fact `"Gene1"` is in a real column and you want to preserve it as a row name, then after `read_excel(...)`, try something like `rownames(Data) <- Data$gene_column_name ; Data$gene_column_name <- NULL`, and then verify that `sapply(Data, is.numeric)` is all true.

Comment: @r2evans - your second guess is almost certainly right.

Comment: I'll update my second comment's code: Don't call `as.matrix` on `Data`, instead after you call `rownames(Data2) <- Data[,1]`, _then_ call `Data2 <- as.matrix(Data2)`.